# ¿Como mostrar el contenido de un AutoCompleteTextView en un formulario para modificar?

Tags: java, android-studio

Anteriormente estaba trabajando con `Spinner` de un registro de producto, pero lo cambie por un `AutoCompleteTextView` el cual sigue trabajando igual sin problemas guardando los registros.

1. UpdateViveres.java

Dentro esta clase tengo agregado la función del `AutoCompleteTextView` para que me muestre la lista desplegable el formulario de registro en los campos con el nombre de seleccione una clasificación y seleccione una presentación.

2. viveresAdapter.java

Dentro de esta clase tengo agregado los métodos para que me muestre la lista de producto en un `RecyclerView`  con su respectivo botón de editar el cual funciona todo bien, también tengo el método para poder editar mediante una ventana de dialogo mostrándome un formulario donde me trae todo los datos sin problemas, el detalle que tengo es que en los campos del  `AutoCompleteTextView` no puedo lograr llamar esa función desplegable ya que cuando le doy clic al icono de arrow para que me muestre las opciones, y mi pregunta es como puedo traer esa función al viveresAdapter.java que tengo el punto No. 1 ya mencionado.

**UpdateVivereS.java**

```
 public class UpdateViveres extends Fragment  {
 private AutoCompleteTextView tipoclasi, tipounidad;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_viveres, container, false);

    tipoclasi =(AutoCompleteTextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.Edit_clasificacion);
    tipounidad =(AutoCompleteTextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.Edit_unidad);

    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   
    tipoclasi = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Edit_clasificacion);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.Clasificacion,R.layout.dropdown_item);
    tipoclasi.setAdapter(adapter1);

    tipounidad = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Edit_unidad);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.Unidad,R.layout.dropdown_item);
    tipounidad.setAdapter(adapter2);
   
  }
  }
```

**viveresAdapter**

```
   public class ViveresAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViveresAdapter.ViveresViewHolder> {

private Context conText;
private List<Vivere> viveresList;

public ViveresAdapter(Context conText, List<Vivere> viveresList) {
    this.conText = conText;
    this.viveresList = viveresList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViveresAdapter.ViveresViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(conText).inflate(R.layout.elementos_viveres,parent,false);


    return new ViveresViewHolder(vista);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViveresAdapter.ViveresViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Vivere vivere = viveresList.get(position);

   holder.texcodigo.setText(vivere.getCodigoViveres());
   holder.texproducto.setText(vivere.getDescriProducto());
   holder.textipoclasi.setText(vivere.getTipoClasificacion());
   holder.texcantidad.setText(""+vivere.getCantidad());
   holder.texunidad.setText(vivere.getUnidadMedida());
   holder.texfecharegistro.setText(vivere.getFechaRegistro());
   holder.texfechacaducidad.setText(vivere.getFechaCaducidad());
   holder.editar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        View edit = LayoutInflater.from(conText).inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_viveres,null);
           EditText texcodigo = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_codigoProduc);
           EditText texproducto = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_descripcion);
           AutoCompleteTextView textipoclasi = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_clasificacion);
           EditText texcantidad = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_cantidad);
           AutoCompleteTextView texunidad = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_unidad);
           EditText texfecharegistro = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_fecha_ingreso);
           EditText texfechacaducidad = edit.findViewById(R.id.Edit_fecha_caducidad);

           texcodigo.setText(vivere.getCodigoViveres());
           texproducto.setText(vivere.getDescriProducto());
           textipoclasi.setText(vivere.getTipoClasificacion());
           texcantidad.setText(String.valueOf(vivere.getCantidad()));
           texunidad.setText(vivere.getUnidadMedida());
           texfecharegistro.setText(vivere.getFechaRegistro());
           texfechacaducidad.setText(vivere.getFechaCaducidad());


           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(conText);
           builder.setTitle("Modificar"+vivere.getCodigoViveres());
           builder.setView(edit);
           builder.setPositiveButton("GUARDAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {

                   final String codigoViveres = texcodigo.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                   final String descriProducto = texproducto.getText().toString();
                   final String tipoClasificacion = textipoclasi.getText().toString();
                   final String cantidad = texcantidad.getText().toString();
                   final String unidadMedida = texunidad.getText().toString();
                   final String fechaRegistro = texfecharegistro.getText().toString();
                   final String fechaCaducidad = texfechacaducidad.getText().toString();
                   final String codigoViveres2 = vivere.getCodigoViveres();

                   if (codigoViveres.isEmpty()||descriProducto.isEmpty()||tipoClasificacion.isEmpty()||cantidad.isEmpty()
                           ||unidadMedida.isEmpty()||fechaRegistro.isEmpty()||fechaCaducidad.isEmpty()){
                       Toast.makeText(conText,"Favor de llenar los campos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   } else {
                       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Urls.UPDATE_VIVERES_URL,
                               new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                                       Toast.makeText(conText, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.lista_viveres);
                                   }
                               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                               Toast.makeText(conText, "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }){
                           @Override
                           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                               params.put("codigoViveres",codigoViveres);
                               params.put("descriProducto",descriProducto);
                               params.put("tipoClasificacion",tipoClasificacion);
                               params.put("cantidad",cantidad);
                               params.put("unidadMedida",unidadMedida);
                               params.put("fechaRegistro",fechaRegistro);
                               params.put("fechaCaducidad",fechaCaducidad);
                               params.put("codigoViveres2",codigoViveres2);
                               return params;
                           }
                       };
                       RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(conText);
                       rQueue.add(stringRequest);
                   }

               }
           });

           builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
           AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
           dialog.show();
       }
   });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return viveresList.size();
}

public class ViveresViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView texcodigo, texproducto,  textipoclasi , texunidad, texcantidad, texfecharegistro,texfechacaducidad;
    Button editar;
    public ViveresViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        texcodigo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textid_codigo);
        texproducto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texDescriProduc);
        textipoclasi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texTipoProduc);
        texcantidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texCantidad);
        texunidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texUnidadMedida);
        texfecharegistro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texFechaRegistro);
        texfechacaducidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texFechaCaducidad);
        editar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEditar);
    }
 }
  }
```

**Captura de imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]